# Equivalence between two definitions of closure of $A\subseteq B$ under a function $f\colon B\to B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

**Synopsis**

In one of the exercises in Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, we are introduced to the concept of the closure of a set to another set under a function $f$ with two constructions.

Let $f$ be a function from $B$ into $B$ and assume that $A \subseteq B$. We have two possible methods for constructing the "closure" $C$ of $A$ under $f$.

First, we have the construction: $$C^* = \bigcap\{X \mid A \subseteq X \subseteq B \wedge f [\![X]\!] \subseteq X \}.$$

Alternatively, we could apply the recursion theorem to obtain the function $h$ for which $$h(0) = A$$ $$h(n^+) = h(n) \cup f[\![h(n)]\!].$$

Define $C_*$ to be $\bigcup \text{ran } h$; in other words: $$C_* = \bigcup_{i \in \omega} h(i).$$

In the exercise, we were asked to prove that $C^* = C_*$, which I was able to do without too much effort. The next exercise, though, which asks us to find the closure $C$ if we take $B$ to be the set of real numbers, $f(x) = x^2$, and $A$ the closed interval $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, confused me a great deal.

This is because the sets $C^*$ and $C_*$ described above make little sense to me intuitively. I have a general idea that the closure of $A$ under $f$ describe how the function $f$ always maps to values within $A$, but I'm not sure how this closure is a set, or how the constructions above elucidate this concept. For example, when people say that the natural numbers are closed under multiplication, how is the closure under multiplication a set? Isn't that just a property?

Anyways, all I've been able to make out from the above exercise with my incomplete understanding is that $1/2$ must be in $C$ and as such, $1/4$, $1/8$, $1/16$ ... all the way to $0$. But I'm not sure if this means that the closure $C$ is the set $[0,1]$. It seems like it might be right, but I can't understand how it fits into the definitions above!

In conclusion, can someone *please* explain to me why the sets $C^*$ and $C_*$ are defined the way they are, and how I can understand the intuition behind them better? I feel like this is all just an issue with me not understanding the formal definitions. I'm self studying this course before I start my first year at university, so you guys are the closest thing I have to a professor! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clive Newstead has addressed the general idea; I’ll take you through the specific example that you mentioned.

If we build $A_*$, forming the closure of $A$ from the bottom up, we start with $h(0)=\left[\frac12,1\right]$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
h(1)&=h(0)\cup\{x^2:x\in h(0)\}\\
&=\left[\frac12,1\right]\cup\left\{x^2:x\in\left[\frac12,1\right]\right\}\\
&=\left[\frac12,1\right]\cup\left[\frac14,1\right]\\
&=\left[\frac14,1\right]\;,
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
h(2)&=h(1)\cup\{x^2:x\in h(1)\}\\
&=\left[\frac14,1\right]\cup\left\{x^2:x\in\left[\frac14,1\right]\right\}\\
&=\left[\frac14,1\right]\cup\left[\frac1{16},1\right]\\
&=\left[\frac1{16},1\right]\;,
\end{align*}$$

and so on. You should be able to convince yourself fairly easily that

$$h(n)=\left[\frac1{2^{2^n}},1\right]$$

and hence that

$$A_*=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\left[\frac1{2^{2n}},1\right]=(0,1]\;.$$

Suppose that instead we work from the top down and compute $A^*$, the intersection of all sets of real numbers that contain $A$ and are closed under the squaring function. A set $X$ of real numbers is closed under the squaring function if $\{x^2:x\in X\}\subseteq X$: $X$ contains the squares of all of its members. Thus,

$$A^*=\bigcap\big\{X\subseteq\Bbb R:A\subseteq X\text{ and }\{x^2:x\in X\}\subseteq X\big\}\;.\tag{1}$$

It’s easy enough to see that $\{x^2:x\in[0,1]\}=[0,1]$, so $[0,1]$ is closed under the squaring function, and certainly $A\subseteq[0,1]$. Thus, $[0,1]$ is one of the sets $X$ that are intersected in $(1)$ to get $A^*$, and therefore we know that $A^*\subseteq[0,1]$. The question is whether $A^*$ is any smaller, i.e., whether there is some set $X$ that is closed under the squaring function — it contains the squares of all of its members — and satisfies the condition $A\subseteq X\subsetneqq[0,1]$. And in fact there is: $(0,1]$ contains $A$ and is closed under the squaring function. We now know that $A^*\subseteq(0,1]$.

It takes a bit of work to show that we can’t cut away any more and still have a set that both contains $A$ and is closed under the squaring function, and I’ll just sketch the argument. Let $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]:x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$, and suppose that $X$ is closed under the squaring function, $A\subseteq X$, and $x_0\in(0,1)$. Given $x_n$ for some $n\in\omega$, let $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$. Then $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is an increasing sequence with limit $1$, so there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $x_n\in A\subseteq X$. But then $x_{n-1}=x_n^2\in X$ (since $X$ is closed under squaring), and then $x_{n-2}=x_{n-1}^2\in X$, and so on all the way down to $x_0\in X$. (This should really be formalized as a downward induction, but the idea should be clear.) This shows that $(0,1)\subseteq X$, and of course we already knew that $1\in A\subseteq X$, so $(0,1]\subseteq X$. That is, on the one hand $(0,1]$ is a set that contains $A$ and is closed under the squaring function, and on the other hand we’ve just seen that any set $X$ that contains $A$ and is closed under the squaring function must contain $(0,1]$, so the intersection of all such sets must **be** $(0,1]$: $A^*=(0,1]$.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your answer. It really helped make everything more clear.

Comment: @mijucik: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Actually, I have another question. Why does the "smallest" set containing $A$ and closed under $f$ matter?

Comment: @mijucik: Sometimes it doesn’t, but often you really do want the minimal extension of some set that is closed under one or more operations. In topology the closure of a set (under the operation of taking limit points) turns out to be a fundamental and indispensable notion. In group theory one needs to be able to take an arbitrary subset $X$ of a group $G$ and find its closure under the group operation — that’s the subgroup of $G$ *generated by* the set $X$: we throw in the absolute minimum necessary to get a subgroup. That such a smallest set exists is in the abstract an important ...

Comment: ... structural fact, but you probably get a real appreciation of the value of such sets only in their specific settings. I don’t think that I could give a good general explanation, at least not without a great deal of thought.

Comment: I see. I still haven't gotten to those courses, but I'm sure there are reasons I'm learning about these sets that'll become useful in my future journey through mathematics. Thank you!

Comment: @mijucik: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 6):

The closure of $A$ under $f$ should be the 'smallest' containing $A$ and closed under $f$.

- $C^*$ characterises what this means from the top down: consider *all* sets that contain $A$ and are closed under $f$. Any such set will all contain the smallest one as a subset, and so the value of the intersection will *be* the smallest one.
- $C_*$ characterises what this means from the bottom up: take the elements of $A$, and keep adding what you get by applying $f$ to what you already have—at the end, you'll have a set containing $A$ and closed under $f$. This is what your function $h$ does: $h(i)$ is the set of things that can be obtained from elements of $A$ by iterating $f$ at most $i$ times.

The fact that $C^*=C_*$ then tells you that the top-down and bottom-up characterisations of 'smallest' coincide.

Comment: Actually, I have another question. Does this property of iterating $f$ have anything to do with the idea of a limit or a convergence? After all, with the function I described above, the closure had a finite cardinality. Is that similar to something like a sequence converging? If the closure was infinite, would that be similar to a sequence diverging? Just wondering.

Comment: Note: I haven't studied analysis yet, so forgive me if I'm getting the ideas totally wrong. I've only taking a computational course on Calculus.

Comment: Kind of. If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then the 'closure' of $A$ (in the sense of topology) is the smallest subset $\overline{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ containing $A$ that is closed under limits of sequences in $A$. That is, if $(x_n)$ Is a sequence in $A$ and $(x_n) \to a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a \in \overline{A}$. We can define $\overline{A}$ to be the intersection of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $A$ that are closed under taking limits of sequences, or equivalently as the union of $A$ and the set of points obtained by taking limits of sequences in $A$.

Comment: [In theory you would need to define a sequence $A_0, A_1, A_2, \dots$ where $A_0=A$ and $A_{n+1}$ is the union of $A_n$ and the limits of sequences in $A_n$, but it so happens that if you do this then $A_1 = A_2 = A_3 = \cdots$ and so the recursion terminates after just one step, giving $A_1 = \overline{A}$.]

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I didn't know set theory was so prominent in topology as well, so this is a really cool fact to know! Thank you!